# Create a directory with ./ folder in java on Windows OS

Tags: java, file, directory, filepath

I am working on a Java project in which the Tar file has to be created. These tar files are created on Linux OS so the folder structure always as : C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Tar\My.tar\.\ 
In this path, the files are kept i.e. if I open My.tar using 7z or anything then I see files within the path : C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Tar\My.tar\.\

Now on windows, I have written the code to generate tar file with some files. But it does not create folder having ./ I want the same structure to be followed to generate tar so that existing code wor fine.

How to create a directory with ./ - C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Tar\My.tar\.\

The code to generate tar file is :

```
FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(outputTarFileName);
            // Create a TarOutputStream
            TarOutputStream out = new TarOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(dest));

            File folder = new File(inputFolder);
            File[] filesToTar = new File[folder.listFiles().length];
            int index = 0;
            for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
                filesToTar[index++] = new File((fileEntry.getAbsolutePath()));
            }
            for (File f : filesToTar) {
                out.putNextEntry(new TarEntry(f, f.getName()));
                BufferedInputStream origin = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
                int count;
                byte data[] = new byte[2048];
                while ((count = origin.read(data)) != -1) {
                    out.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                out.flush();
                origin.close();
            }
            out.close();




createTarFile("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Tar\\MyDir","C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Tar\\\\.\\My.tar");
```

I tried by creating a directory having such structure :

new File("C:\Users\Admin.000\Desktop\testfolder\./\W").mkdir();

new File("C:\Users\Admin.000\Desktop\testfolder\\.\W").mkdir();

But nothing worked.

Comment: What have you tried? share your code Snippet

Comment: In windows the folder with ./ is not allowed to be created